# Cambridge Z88 Production Run

Tags: sinclair

While this is not a technical question per se, I finally found something I have no idea and couldn't find any answer online:

**How many [Cambridge Z88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_Z88)s were made and/or sold?**

As it's related, a sub-question would be **How long was the Z88 in production?**

Delivery started in Jun 1987 and lasted at least until late 1989, but when did production really stop?

---

After much searching through real paper, I found a September 1987 issue of the UK magazine *Popular Computing Weekly* mentioning a production capacity of 1000 units per week and an intention to double this 'soon' to 2000. The same issue also features a short article about a deal with SCI, a larger US manufacturing company, to set up production at their Scottish plant. Still no added up production numbers.

---

Another hint, I just noticed, that one of my Z88s carries a 'Made in Scotland by SCI UK LTD' sticker with a serial number of 007092:

[image]

So there were at least 7000 units produced in the SCI plant. Also, since the contract was mentioned in the September 1987 issue in future form, it may be safe to assume that Cambridge LTD manufactured Z88s in their own works for at least 6 months, adding another 6-10k units. So ~20k can be seen as the absolute lowest limit.

Comment: No idea either. I have proof for *one* right here in the drawer.

Comment: @tofro That makes it two :) - Right now I would be already happy about any (educated) guess.

Comment: If anyone would know, [Rakewell](http://www.rakewell.com/z88/z88.shtml) would. They've been supporting the Z88 since it came out. I bought Z88 accessories from them back in the day.

Comment: @tofro Mind to check ifyours got some sticker/serial number?

Comment: My number (Of a German Keyboard Z88, so pretty late in the game) is significantly higher: 0057903. Rest is identical. But also "Made in Scotland by Sci UK Ltd".  This *could* imply there were at least that many made.

Comment: @tofro Cool. Thanks. I'd say this puts it at least past 60k units.  And no, a German Keyboard isn't any indicator for being late, as it was available form the start. Above unit (7092) is also German.

Comment: A higher serial number is here: [C014593](http://www.larwe.com/museum/z88.html)

Comment: I wouldn't assume serial numbering started at 000001.  It's possible, but sometimes companies start at 010000 because psychologically, people don't always want to get very low-serialed equipment.  (Later, in the collector market, of course, those low numbers are gold if the equipment is at all in demand :) )

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Sure, but as said, my unit is 007092, and there are even lower ones known like [000698](https://www.flashbackgames.co.uk/ShopResources/2296/Thumbs/IMG_3564.jpg). Even more so, as these are all SCI numbers, which only started to produce the Z88 in late 1987, so even before SCI#000001 ther must be at leaast 6-10,000 units done by Cambridges own shops.

Comment: @Raffzahn If you know there's a 000698, odds are good indeed that they started at or near 000001 then :)

Comment: @Raffzahn - Cambridge, like Sinclair before it, didn't have any manufacturing facilities. Many Spectrums were made by Timex in Dundee, and SCI in Irvine would have picked up some of IBM's formerly Spango Valley manufacture by the late 1980s.

Comment: @scruss As mentioned, this information is taken from that September issue of Popular Computing Weekly, where they explain that the production with a quota of 1000 Units per week started at Cambridges own fabrication, intended to go up to 2000/week soon and that a contract with SCI has been fixed to hand over production to their plant in Scotland larter the year. I don't mind if you can add more here.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.wired.com/2010/10/how-the-allies-used-math-against-german-tanks/

Comment: @traal Jup, known, except as of now, we only have an extreme small sample of less than 10 while at the same time the upper known number is rather high in comparsion. So we need to shoot a few more Z88 to get their numbers :))  With that formula, the actual sample comes down to ~67500 Units - with a variance allowing an upper end in the millions. So again, lets shoot more.

Comment: Some serial numbers from eBay: 022979, made in Scotland. 053838 Scotland. 023741 Scotland. 010569 Scotland. 000795 Scotland. 005655 Scotland. 0062271 Scotland. 010759 Scotland.

Comment: Also there are some with no serial number badge.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160306232450/http://www.pagetable.com/?p=547

Comment: @Traal I guess the seller simply didn't find them. The serial # is hidden under the folding keyboard foot.

Comment: @traal did you read the comments? It's always funny how blindly fanboys can bee. Someone sits down and does a real great job in collectin information and puting them in a consistent form and they still go _'nananana but I know its <beloved-phantasy-number>'_ :)) (And thanks for the numbers - the tank formula now gives 66718 as total)

Comment: @tofro Some may also have been removed, as the sticker has been (usually) placed over one of the screws that hold the case together.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of my Z88 - It received an internal ROM and RAM upgrade to 512 kBytes each today ;) (Had to rip the serial number, though, as one of the screws hides under it)

Comment: Had no idea SCI had a plant in Scotland, interesting tidbit, SCI stood for Space Craft, Incorporated - they got their start making components for the Apollo program.

Answer (score 25):

I know it's bad style to answer ones own question. Still,I feel the need to publish my findings (*1):

Over the last <strike>3</strike> <strike>18</strike> <strike>26 months</strike> 5 years(*2) I've been able to collect serial numbers of 56 different Z88s, with **62271** (still) being the largest.

Using the so called [German Tank Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem), as [traal](/q/6006) suggested, yields **63382** as a result. So it might be safe to assume that there were considerable less than 100,000 units, possibly even **less than 65,000**. Unless there's some hidden stash with high serial numbers, that is.

As with many statistical methods there are other approaches and concerns, but Michael Steil has already used it twice to generate rather believable numbers [for the C64](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=547) as well as [for the Xbox](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=465), While others made a believable case for iPhones. So I'm inclined to go with it.

---

Fun part: As so often, [the comments](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=547#comments) of anything about the C64 does carry the outcry of the fanboys. This time it's *'nananana ... statistics are neat but **I know better** and it's <beloved-fantasy-number>'*

---

*1 - Beside, no-one has provided any answer so far.

*2 - It's getting harder to find more - so Gents, please go thru your storage and pull out your Z88 (I know you got one - everyone has to have one) and post your serial number as comment. There are still many usable lines in my VisiCalc sheet:

[image]

Comment: Agreed to the fun part, to the extent that I wish I could give you a second +1 for it; my favourite was "it’s not the best research if you don’t know how to get to those numbers". So we've all been wrong about research all this time: the "best research" is starting from a conclusion and finding a way to get to it!

Comment: Not sure it's bad style to answer one's own question; that's encouraged practise here on SE.

Comment: @Wilson I think it is. Beside from the stupidity to ask something one knows to answer, the software is made to disencurage it. So yeah, bad style. And I would have seriously prefered some pointers over my own guessing the number game.

Comment: Suggest you read https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer, this is *explicitly* encouraged across the entire SE network. If you think differently, you should probably work with meta to get the suggestion changed, but I don't think you'll have much luck since it's a great way to get more knowledge on to the sites.

Comment: @paxdiablo Beside that it might be a good idea to abstain from a patronizing tone, even more so it is of no good to spread out a discusion from it's original location. I feel it might not only be a good idea, but quite useful to read prior comments before commenting. Wilson has exactly pointed out the same and I already did make my point clear. Reading helps to avoide superfluous drivel.

Comment: (1) Was not my intent to be patronising, just to explain why self-answering is acceptable. (2) The discussion is not being "spread", the comment you make about it being bad form is *here* hence my response is here. (3) Wilson did not provide the link that states self-answering is okay, I would think that would be added valuable informtion, myself.

Comment: Self-answering is a good thing if you find an answer yourself finally, especially if no-one else found one, and even if it's not 100%. Most professional questioners will go on with their research after posting their question, and I presume we here are such. I think it's better to have a self-given answer than none. But, Raffzahn, which reasons do you have?

Comment: @thebusybee Not really. While you're right from a theoretical POV, reality made me notice, that more often than not, OPs adding their own answer either do so right away, which means it hasn't been a real question at all, but rather a misuse of RC.SE as some blog, or they use it to force their point - including their ability to choose the 'right' answer. Both ways do not benefit RC.SE at all. And while I think above is none of both but useful, I still feel the need to make it clear that I'm not intending either. I also will never select my  own answer as 'the right' one.

Comment: @Raffzahn Or, it is a question that took me a long time to find the answer to, which would have benefited me greatly had it been on SE.  So I will create the question I had hours ago, then add the answer I just now found, hoping that some other person with the same question will benefit from my hard-won answer.  It looks to you like both the question and answer occurred at the same time, but in my timeline, they did not.

Comment: If the purpose of RC.SE is to be a repository of information, then aren't brain dumps appropriate here? Or do we really need to wait for someone to ask a question before we can answer it?

Comment: To my understanding, RC.SE is not a braindump in any way. That's what facebook, twitter and personal blogs are about. It is also not meant to collect an encyclopedia of topics. That's what Wikipedia (and specialized wikis) are for. RC.SE's **primary function**, as a site, is to help people stuck at an issue by having others go over it and provide hints or in best case solutions.By keeping these solutions permanent available a repository is created. Which serves a great **secondary function**. That's what differentiates RC.SE from other sites - at the core is always a real issue to be solved.

Comment: Would not 65536 be the best guess?

Comment: @JonCuster :)) Well, at the actual number of probes, this would need someine binging a 64112. THen again, I do not belive that some company folding up a business has that much fun.

Comment: mine's 60806, late model with sealed edge port, made in Irvine (pr. /ur-vihn/, near enough: I'm from near there) by SCI like all the rest

Comment: @scruss I think we added that already some time ago, didn't we?

Comment: @Raffzahn - perhaps, yes

Answer (score 5):

my piece is # 000040 isn't one of the first ?
[image]

Comment: It's for sure the lowest I recorded so far. Are you the original buyer?

Answer (score 2):

My Z88 serial number is #034368.

Comment: VLQ reviewers: this can be an useful hint to estimate the count of the sold Z88s. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Just for evidence - my one has serial #24672: [image]

Comment: Well, It lowers the estimate by anotehr 38 to 63789.

Answer (score 1):

My Z88 is a SCI UK Ltd, Made in Scotland model with the serial number #0059854.

Comment: Interesting, third highest so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Serial Numbers for My Z88 (Serial #000169) and that for my Wife's Z88 (Serial #026554).  We bought them at different times, hence the large difference.
[image: Serial #000169 of my Z88]

[image: Serial #026554 of my Wife's Z88]

Comment: Huh, 169 is pretty low. In fact, the lowest I've recorded so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes serial from mine z88.
Was bought in Croatia and during retro meetings it came to Novi Sad, Serbia.
Added two pic because one is not so clear.
[[image: Z88 serial num][1]]

Answer (score 1):

I am adding second pic. Looks like I can't post more than one.
[image: Second pic]